# How to Use A[n][n] in function?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, variable-length-array

I am studying CSAPP and the book says we can use this following code :

```
#include <cstddef>
int var_ele(size_t n, int A[n][n], size_t i, size_t j) {
    return A[i][j];
}
```

but I cannot compile this. The book says in the past we need to write like this :

```
#define IDX(n, i, j) ((i)*(n)+(j))
/* Get element A[i][j] */
int vec_ele(size_t n, int *A, size_t i, size_t j){
    return A[IDX(n,i,j)];
}
```

I use command :

```
gcc -S -Og nn_matrix_code.cpp
```

on Ubuntu and the compiler says :

```
nn_matrix_code.cpp:2:30: error: use of parameter outside function body before ‘]’ token
    2 | int var_ele(size_t n, int A[n][n], size_t i, size_t j) {
      |                              ^
nn_matrix_code.cpp:2:33: error: use of parameter outside function body before ‘]’ token
    2 | int var_ele(size_t n, int A[n][n], size_t i, size_t j) {
      |                                 ^
nn_matrix_code.cpp:2:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token
    2 | int var_ele(size_t n, int A[n][n], size_t i, size_t j) {
      |            ~                     ^
      |                                  )
nn_matrix_code.cpp:2:43: error: expected initializer before ‘i’
    2 | int var_ele(size_t n, int A[n][n], size_t i, size_t j) {
      |                                           ^
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: The problem could be if you're trying to compile that as C++.  ISO C supports VLAs (variable-length arrays), C++ doesn't (except as an extension in some compilers; e.g. GCC but not MSVC).  You tagged this [compiler-errors], but you didn't actually show any or mention any compilers.

Comment: I've modified my question.

Comment: GCC supports VLAs in C++ mode (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), but apparently only inside functions, not for this use of function args.  (Unless that's a compiler bug?  But all GCC versions on Godbolt seem the same.  https://godbolt.org/z/nT3TvPxbh).  Clang accepts it in C++ mode.  Anyway, this is not valid ISO C++, but is valid C.  GCC compiles it just fine as C: https://godbolt.org/z/TPKc9f4qq

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I change it into C and it can compile. I once thought C++ should compile all C code.

Comment: hahaha :P  Try `int *p = malloc(16);` for another example.  (Implicit conversion from `void*`)

Comment: Does the book really say to write exactly what you have written in your first code block? That is neither valid C nor C++. Which of the two languages is the book intending to teach?

Comment: Don't use `gcc` to compile C++ programs. Use `g++` - otherwise you'll get problems when linking later. If you change to C, then include `stddef.h` instead of `cstddef`

Comment: Your code uses variable-length arrays (array with length determined at run time).   VLA's are a feature of C.   VLAs are NOT part of standard C++.   Unfortunately, some C++ compilers (but certainly not all) partially support VLAs as a NON STANDARD extension (and your particular manner of usage is often the part that is not supported even by C++ compilers that do support VLAs).   If your textbook is telling you that such things are standard C++, get another textbook.   [BTW:  VLAs are often considered poor practice in C, too].